# Android / Java rare and seemingly impossible exception causing force close

Tags: java, android, arrays, exception, multidimensional-array

I have an interesting problem being reported to me from an android application I have published. I have a two-dimensional array that I am iterating through using two for loops like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; ++j)
    {
        if (arr[i][j] != 0)
            // does stuff
    }
}
```

The problem is, somehow arr[i][j] != 0 is throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. But very rarely. I have thousands of people use the app on a daily basis and get maybe twenty force close reports.

Is this something I can't avoid, maybe a problem with the phones memory, etc. or is there something I can do that I haven't thought of yet? Thanks.

Comment: Its probably not going to be just the loop control as this is pretty simplistic. Its more likely going to be access of the arrays inside the loop or asynchronously, or modification of the counter j. You will need to post more specific code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This exception is not impossible if you have one thread reading the arrays while a second thread is mutating them.  Specifically, if the mutating thread is changing the size of array slices; e.g.

```
array[i] = new Whatever[array[i].length - 1];
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, I must have a sync leak somewhere. Thanks